How can I migrate the ensureIndexes with Morphia from 1.6 to 2.4?
I am migrating Morphia from 1.6 to 2.4.
We are running the ensureIndexes on our application starting.
But, We caught warning messages as follow.
Mapper#map is configured in the config file and should not be called directly.

Then, I read the morphia document as follow.
https://morphia.dev/morphia/2.4/javadoc/dev/morphia/Datastore.html#ensureIndexes()
I can see that I can config a ensureIndexes by a config file.
How can I config the ensureIndex by file?

You can create the MorphiaConfig and programmatically and configure starting with MorphiaConfig.load().  If you go the config file route, you can set morphia.apply-indexes=true.  The complete file structure can be seen here.  The complete configuration docs can be found here
